# Woocommerce: Adding a product variation to the cart and also with increased quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity, product-variations

How do i add the selected product variation and - if the quantity is increased - the updated quantity to the cart? Code below works fine if i only add 1 product to the cart if it has no variations.

In page-shop.php (the main shop page, no deep links to products wanted) i'm getting all the food of category "vorspeisen" (appetizer):

```
<div class="clearfix trichter" id="vorspeisen">
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="trichtertitel" data-aos="flip-up"><h2><span>1</span>Zuerst eine feine Vorspeise</h2></div>
 <?php $args = array(
      'post_type'      => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'product_cat'    => 'vorspeisen'
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post();global $product;?>
  <?php include 'single-food.php';?>
  <?php endwhile;wp_reset_query();?>
  </div>
```

and in the included single-food.php i'm getting all the needed infos about the appetizer (thumbnail, title) and also all product variations with differenz prizes:

```
<article class="prdct_holder clearfix" id="p<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="lefty">
<?php $img0 = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($product->ID),'prdct');?>
<img src="<?php echo $img0[0];?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
</div>
<div class="righty">
<h1><?php echo get_the_title();?></h1>
<?php if( '' !== get_post()->post_content ) { ?>
  <div class="contento">
    <?php echo onlytext();?>

    <form class="cart" action="?add-to-cart=<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>#<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <?php // do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
      <?php  $min_value = 0; $max_value = -1; $input_value = 1; $step = 1; $pattern = ''; $inputmode = 'numeric'; $input_id = ''; $input_name = 'quantity';?>

        <div class="quantity">
          <label class="screen-reader-text" for="product<?php echo esc_attr($product->get_id());?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
          <div class="quantity-button minus"><span>-</span></div>
          <input type="number" id="product<?php echo esc_attr($product->get_id());?>" class="input-text qty text" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( 0 < $max_value ? $max_value : '' ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>"
            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" size="4" pattern="<?php echo esc_attr( $pattern ); ?>" inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr( $inputmode ); ?>" />
          <div class="quantity-button plus"><span>+</span></div>
        </div>

<?php  if ($product->is_type('variable')){
global $product; // echo 'ist variabel!<br>';

$attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
$attribute_keys = array_keys( $attributes );
?>

<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
        <td class="value">
            <?php
                $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( urldecode( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                $args = array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected );
                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( $args );

            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php } ?>
<a href="/shop/?add-to-cart=<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>#p<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"
    value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>"
    class="ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button" data-product_id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"
     aria-label="<?php the_title_attribute() ?> zum Warenkorb hinzufügen"><div class="add"><span>+</span> Bestellen!</div></a>
        <?php // do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
    </form>
  </div>
<?php }?>

</div>
</article>
```